# Regex Finding the last block of content where required email is present

Tags: python-3.x, regex

Sample raw data:

```
asdas wqdqw Start wqqwdsad Received new email message
asdasd
asdas
dasd
asd
asd
asdasdas Email = testa@asd.com
asdnaslfbasl
asdas wqdasdwqqeqw Start wqqwdsaadsd Received new email message
asdasd
asdas
dasd
asd
asd
asdasdasEmail = testa@asd.com
asdnaslfbaslasdnaslfbasl
asdas wqdqw Start wqqwdsad Received new email message

asdsa
asdsadasd
asdasdasEmail = test@asd.com
asdnaslfbasl
asdas wqdqw Start wqqwdsad Received new email message
asdnaslfbasl
asdasdasEmail = test@asd.com
asdas wqdqw Start wqqwdsadReceived new email message
asda
as
asdasdasEmail = testa@asd.com
asdnaslfbasl
asdnaslfbasl
asdas wqdqw Start wqqwdsadReceived new email message
```

Expected output:

```
asdas wqdqw Start wqqwdsad Received new email message
asdasd
asdas
dasd
asd
asd
asdasdas Email = testa@asd.com

asdas wqdasdwqqeqw Start wqqwdsaadsd Received new email message
asdasd
asdas
dasd
asd
asd
asdasdasEmail = testa@asd.com

asdas wqdqw Start wqqwdsadReceived new email message
asda
as
asdasdasEmail = testa@asd.com
```

I'm new to regex and would like to extract all blocks with email = testa@asd.com up to the 1st precedent "Received new email message"

I've tried:

```
\b.*Received new email message[\s\S]*?(?=\n.*Email = testa@asd\.com)
```

It works great for the 1st 2 blocks, but for the 3rd block, it gives me:

```
asdas wqdqw Start wqqwdsad Received new email message

asdsa
asdsadasd
asdasdasEmail = test@asd.com
asdnaslfbasl
asdas wqdqw Start wqqwdsad Received new email message
asdnaslfbasl
asdasdasEmail = test@asd.com
asdas wqdqw Start wqqwdsadReceived new email message
asda
as
```

Appreciate any help to get me going in the right direction

Comment: What did you expect? Your email in your third block is `test@asd.com` io `testa@asd.com`, perhaps that's all there is to it.

Comment: My expectation for the 3rd block would be only for the last Received new email message to match:asdas wqdqw Start wqqwdsadReceived new email message
asda
as
asdasdasEmail = testa@asd.com. I don;t want the blocks without testa@asd.com to be in the output

Comment: Ah, I see. You need something like a negative lookbehind but I can't figure it out either. Unless someone knows how to do that in one regex, an alternative is to do it in two steps. `Received new email message$\n.*?\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}\b` retrieves all individual mails. You can then inspect each match on being send to `testa@asd.com` and retain/delete the match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the job:

```
^.+?Received new email message(?:(?!Received new email message)[\s\S])+?Email = testa@asd\.com
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/Sy5imR/1)

**Code:**

```
import re

string = r'''asdas wqdqw Start wqqwdsad Received new email message
asdasd
asdas
dasd
asd
asd
asdasdas Email = testa@asd.com
asdnaslfbasl
asdas wqdasdwqqeqw Start wqqwdsaadsd Received new email message
asdasd
asdas
dasd
asd
asd
asdasdasEmail = testa@asd.com
asdnaslfbaslasdnaslfbasl
asdas wqdqw Start wqqwdsad Received new email message

asdsa
asdsadasd
asdasdasEmail = test@asd.com
asdnaslfbasl
asdas wqdqw Start wqqwdsad Received new email message
asdnaslfbasl
asdasdasEmail = test@asd.com
asdas wqdqw Start wqqwdsadReceived new email message
asda
as
asdasdasEmail = testa@asd.com
asdnaslfbasl
asdnaslfbasl
asdas wqdqw Start wqqwdsadReceived new email message'''

res = re.findall(r'.+?Received new email message(?:(?!Received new email message)[\s\S])+?Email = testa@asd\.com', string)
print res
```

**Output:**

```
['asdas wqdqw Start wqqwdsad Received new email message\nasdasd\nasdas\ndasd\nasd\nasd\nasdasdas Email = testa@asd.com', 'asdas wqdasdwqqeqw Start wqqwdsaadsd Received new email message\nasdasd\nasdas\ndasd\nasd\nasd\nasdasdasEmail = testa@asd.com', 'asdas wqdqw Start wqqwdsadReceived new email message\nasda\nas\nasdasdasEmail = testa@asd.com']
```